# How can I figure out whether a reaction is endothermic or exothermic without its enthalpy value?

Tags: thermodynamics, enthalpy

I already know the way to determine whether if the given reaction is exothermic or endothermic by the enthalpy values. But is it possible without enthalpy values, and just by looking at the reaction?

So as far as I know there are two types of chemical reactions, namely one way reactions and reversible reactions.

So how can I determine this factor in **one way reactions** and **reversible reactions**?

I guess that for reversible reactions we can use equilibrium constants such as $K_p$, $K_c$, but I am not quite sure whether it is correct. On the other hand, I feel that there is no such way to determine what I want in one way reactions. So how can I decide it?

Comment: Hello everyone , I want to know whether the English that I have used  here  is  good enough or is it horrible?Because I am not a native Englishman.If so please show me that mistakes also, while you  helping me to come out of this question.

Comment: I don't think there is a way. The concept of enthalpy came to be for a reason.

Comment: You can make an educated guess based on the relative strengths of the bonds broken vs bonds formed.

Comment: @On the way, your English is quite good. It might need some polishing, but then what are the editors for? So no worries. :) Also, regarding your question, if one knows about the bond strengths in both reactants and products (for example they'd say an F-F bond is way weaker than say, an H-H bond) , they *could* decide the sign of enthalpy, but it would be very very crude and it could lead to wrong results. Unfortunately, I have nothing else related in my mind right now.

Comment: @M.A.Ramezani I agree that using bond strengths would lead to a very crude estimate, but if you only want the sign of $\Delta H$ and not the magnitude, for 99% of reactions it should suffice. The 1% would be when your estimated $\Delta H$ is close to 0. Regarding the question itself, I'm just nitpicking here but all reactions are reversible except for reactions where a product escapes from the system. As such, you can theoretically use le Chatelier's principle to determine whether the reaction is exothermic or endothermic based on the change in equilibrium position when temperature changes.

Comment: @M.A.Ramezani:  Then how about comparing equilibrium constants at different temperatures? (by the way thank for check-up you did for my question)

Comment: After thinking about it I think I have exaggerated quite a bit. If you only had access to a table of bond energies you would only be able to estimate enthalpies for gas-phase reactions; for any other reactions involving solid/liquid/aqueous reactants you would have to consider lots of other factors such as intermolecular forces, lattice energies, enthalpies of hydration etc... After lots of experience in chemistry it might be possible to identify whether a reaction is exo/endothermic at first glance, e.g. thermal decomposition of CaCO3 is endothermic. But in the absence of data it's not easy.

Comment: @ orthocresol: How about using equilibrium constants?

Comment: If you know the signs of the Gibbs' energy change and entropy change you could use Δ _G_ = Δ _H_ - _T_ Δ _S_. For instance, if you know that the reaction is spontaneous (Δ _G_ is negative) and the products have a lower entropy than the reactants (Δ _S_ is negative), then you know that the reaction must be exothermic because Δ _H_ must be negative.

Comment: @ Derek: Okay so , is it possible to find if a reversible reaction is exothermic or endothermic by Kp and Kc  value.?

Comment: How about going into the lab, mixing the reactants, and observing whether they react, and if so, does the flask warm up.

Comment: You can use the value of the equilibrium constant to determine Δ G. If K is 1 then Δ G is 0, if K is greater than 1 then Δ G is negative, and if K is less than 1 then Δ G is positive. This is because Δ G = -RT ln K. Δ G can then be used to find Δ H, per my previous comment.

Comment: It means , there is no way to compare Kp and Kc  in-order to have a clue about the type of reaction  thermodynamically.(either exothermic or endothermic)?

Comment: Then how about comparing two Kp values at two different temperatures ?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the equilibrium constant $K$ in general doesn't tell too much about the enthalpy change of the reaction as it is related to the (Gibbs) free energy change $\Delta G = \Delta H - T\Delta S$. It is true that in some simple cases (such as gas phase reactions) the  entropy change can be approximated by looking at the stoichiometry of the reaction but in general it's usually more complicated.

Regarding your distinction between one-way and reversible reactions I think you may as well assume all reactions are reversible, but some have incredibly huge $K$ so the equilibrium is shifted totally to one side of the reaction - this is the result of a very negative $\Delta G$.

In case of a "reversible" reaction you can always look at the change of the equilibrium constant with temperature. The constant is

$K = \exp\left(-\frac{\Delta G}{RT}\right)=\exp\left(-\frac{\Delta H}{RT}\right)\exp\left(\frac{\Delta S}{R}\right)$

so from the temperature dependence you can deduce the sign of $\Delta H$. Naturally, this is assuming that $\Delta H$ and $\Delta S$ doesn't depend on the temperature in the temperature range you're looking at.

[image: equilibrium constant vs temperature]

The figure shows the change of equilibrium constant with temperature (arbitrary units) for an exothermic (yellow line) and an endothermic (blue line) reaction.

Just by looking at the reaction I don't think you can tell the enthalpy change. Normally you have bonds breaking on the reactant side and others forming on the product side and normally there is a delicate balance between the two. People have come up with bond strength values (which could be determined from known $\Delta H$ values) and you can use those in your reaction.

Comment: How about comparing equilibrium constants  at two different temperatures ?

Comment: But can't we compare  Kp ,Kc for  different temperatures , and then come to a conclusion?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have modified the post so it makes much more sense.

Comment: If you would give few examples that would be great.

Comment: Then how about comparing two Kp values at two different temperatures ?

Comment: If I compare Kp value at two different temperatures would I be able to find whether the reaction is exothermic or endothermic?

Comment: Well, yes. Look at the figure I added to my answer, it show how the equilibrium constant changes with temperature for exothermic or endothermic reactions.

Comment: Hey albapa , is this valid for Kp and Kc?

Comment: You need to look at the temperature dependence of Kp and Kc. I guess Kp has an extra temperature term so it's slightly more complicated.

Comment: Anyhow, can I use this theory to determine what I want? regardless of Kp or Kc?

Answer (score 0):

If the enthalpies of formation for all reactants and products are known then you can compute the standard enthalpy change ($\Delta H^\circ$).

If they are not known you can estimate $\Delta H^\circ$ using bond energies as described in [this video](https://youtu.be/-bqKZi63x6U).

Finally if you happen to know that the reaction is spontaneous ($\Delta G^\circ < 0$) and if the standard entropy change is (likely) negative (e.g. if the number of particles decrease) then it must be an exothermic reaction.

Comment: not sure what you mean by "one way" and "reversible" reactions

Comment: @ Jan Jensen:I used one way to indicate the reactions which have one solid forward arrow, while reversible for ones which are in equilibrium.

Comment: $\ce{A -> B}$ means that at equilibrium there is more $\ce{A}$ than $\ce{B}$, while $\ce{A} \rightleftarrows \ce{B}$ suggests that there is roughly an equal amount of  $\ce{A}$ and $\ce{B}$.  However, both usually imply equilibrium $\ce{A <=> B}$.  Either way, thus does not affect how you would estimate endo/exothermicity.